# CSS styling working offline only for a specific div

Tags: css

I'm embedding a code editor (from Codejar) and everything works great until I tried it online, all the CSS works perfect except the text editor div. I think the CSS styling of this div doesn't apply anymore even if all the files are uploaded correctly...

```
<div class="editor language-js" id="editeur" data-gramm="false"> **Sample code** import {CodeJar}... </div>
```

By the way

[How it shows Offline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubnzV.jpg)

[How it shows Online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTgPJ.jpg)

The styling is part of the main.css file under .editor class and i manage to make it work online only if I write inline styling on the html page..

---

Don't think the problem comes from the CSS file itself but anyway :

```
.editor {
width: 100%;
color: #fff;
background: #272822;
border-radius: 0px;
box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
font-family: monospace;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 700;
min-height: 240px;
letter-spacing: normal;
line-height: 20px;
padding: 55px;
tab-size: 4;}
```

---

I think it's maybe from the html code that links the css files (and yes the files linked are uploaded correctly) :

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/svgicons.css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="prism/themes/prism-darcula.css">
    <style>
    @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300&family=PT+Mono&display=swap");
    </style>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, I can't see where you're embedding the stylesheets of the editor. Can you create a quick minimal reproducible solution here to let us see your (coding) problem?

Comment: Generally speaking, if your offline and online output is different, you should check the stylesheets and scripts that are loaded from the outside (have mostly links beginning with http:// or https:// and not going to your own domain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to clear the cache of your browser, or just temporarily bypass it will ctrl+f5.

Also, try it in different browsers and see if some work and others don't.